# IP Address Converter

Tags: bash, ip, converters

There is IP address: 66.102.13.19, and from this address as that received this address

```
http://1113984275
```

But how? And how I can make this with the help of bash.
For example, [this service](http://www.csgnetwork.com/ipaddconv.html) can do it, but I do not understand the algorithm.

Answer (score 40):

```
ip=66.102.13.19
IFS=. read -r a b c d <<< "$ip"
printf '%s%d\n' "http://" "$((a * 256 ** 3 + b * 256 ** 2 + c * 256 + d))"
```

By the way, the number in your question doesn't match the IP address.

To convert a decimal to an IP:

```
#!/bin/bash
dec2ip () {
    local ip delim dec=$@
    for e in {3..0}
    do
        ((octet = dec / (256 ** e) ))
        ((dec -= octet * 256 ** e))
        ip+=$delim$octet
        delim=.
    done
    printf '%s\n' "$ip"
}

dec2ip "$@"
```

To convert an IP to a decimal:

```
#!/bin/bash
ip2dec () {
    local a b c d ip=$@
    IFS=. read -r a b c d <<< "$ip"
    printf '%d\n' "$((a * 256 ** 3 + b * 256 ** 2 + c * 256 + d))"
}

ip2dec "$@"
```

Demo:

```
$ ./dec2ip 1113984275
66.102.13.19

$ ./ip2dec 66.102.13.19
1113984275
```

These two scripts rely on features of Bash that aren't present in some Bourne-derived shells. Here are AWK versions to use instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
# dec2ip
BEGIN {
    dec = ARGV[1]
    for (e = 3; e >= 0; e--) {
        octet = int(dec / (256 ^ e))
        dec -= octet * 256 ^ e
        ip = ip delim octet
        delim = "."
    }
    printf("%s\n", ip)
}
```

and

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
# ip2dec
BEGIN {
    ip = ARGV[1]
    split(ip, octets, ".")
    for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        dec += octets[i] * 256 ** (4 - i)
    }
    printf("%i\n", dec)
}
```

They can be called in the same manner as the Bash scripts above.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: The decimal number for the given IP address is 1113984275

Comment: Thank you for your decision, more clear, I corrected the error.

And how do the inverse operation? From the 1113984275 to get 66.102.13.19.

Comment: @ArmenB.: I'm not sure what you're asking, but yes, typically anything which can be done in a shell script can be done at the command line and vice versa. There are exceptions or cases where things have to be done a little differently. In this case, you could include the functions (just the function definition omitting the shebang and the call to the function) in a file such as `~/bin/functions` and source that from your `~/.bashrc` using `. $HOME/bin/functions` (notice the dot). Then you could call the functions from the command line like this: `ip2dec 66.102.13.19`, for example.

Comment: If you mean a different shell other than Bash, then yes, but it might have to be rewritten if the other shell doesn't have the same features as Bash which are used here.

Comment: @Dennis: Yes by other other shell I meant `sh` not `bash`. I'm looking for a way to do this is vanilla shell.

Comment: @ArmenB.: Unfortunately, the Bourne shell doesn't support arrays (although you could use `set` and the positional parameters) and neither it nor `expr` support exponentiation. Also, different versions of Bourne-derived shells support (or not) a variety of other features. So to get something usable, I've added AWK versions. Hopefully they work with the version of AWK you're using.

Comment: I think this would be better-expressed with binary functions (<<) rather than exponents.

Comment: Notice from ip to decimal to init the dec value before the loop, otherwise it continue to increase  :)

Comment: @shacharsol: If you're referring to the AWK version of `ip2dec`, `dec` is initialized automatically to a null value when the `BEGIN` clause first encounters it. If you use it outside `BEGIN` perhaps by defining a function then you probably would need to explicitly initialize it.

Comment: Multiplication is slow, a faster alternative is to use bit shifting (a one opcode command to most CPUs) `printf '%d\n' "$(( (a<<24) + (b<<16) + (c<<8) + d ))"`

Comment: @Isaac: But this isn't C, this is Bash. Did you actually test the difference? For me, in Bash 4.4, my multiplication is about 15% faster than your shifts. `time for i in {1..1000000}; do printf '%s%d\n' "http://" "$((a * 256 ** 3 + b * 256 ** 2 + c * 256 + d))"; done > /dev/null`

Comment: I should have tested longer. Was faster in ksh. Here is a comparison for shells: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVJbboMwEPznFCPLyIaI0pA2rRLSI/QE/QEMAhUMxU4@@jg7tR3yqtSRsHa9u7O7g/NM1dMk@m7faoAHXxjGRuoKzFe@eJMMpNZ62MQxAaGcZwiRPK4RhlhhgfziJsYtZncBEQRkix/PE72qm0pfU5MjNflDDZ6lafIQmGqep@ly7awiTZ@tIXBknORueW/hYYZX9SNUjUYiN9vg3Xyfqt5C9C7HhvtBN720KfOq81jnJAuls1HvKBeZLrGwAqxeWXAOW1DDHRVglrOxdJSr8gOMUElYcMN2golxURZtNpaIBrM9PQ5DAsK27Oyxm0LRyxIviEV5iOW@bS/RUor/R5wFjg4g416eqJ26pi5yCxoZvVMLz1ndjprsozDuQs0XTiLvipj5a4UN/GWi5uPpblX5vnsnRhvbqrOHck1RFnUPwmkXURXEVIXm1xF8Iy8QtTCDeHaK6Rc "Bash – Try It Online")

Comment: It shows an small improvement in ksh and zsh, but not so big. In any case, it doesn't work in dash (which I didn't mention before) because dash doesn't have the exponentiation operator (`**`). Maybe you will like the dash compatible version of `d + (c + (b + a * 256)*256)*256`

Comment: @Isaac: Wow, zsh is slow!

Comment: You want a Fast shell?: try dash [Try it online!](http://shorturl.at/mLV04)

Comment: There's a problem with your ip2dec script. It adds a trailing zero at the end.

Comment: @madacoda: Is it the Bash version or the Awk one? I'm not getting one in either version. Can you give me an example IP that results in an extra trailing zero? That bug would require either concatenations (which aren't used in either script) or multiplication (directly or indirectly) by 10 (also not present). I did, however, just discover a bug in my Bash version of `dec2ip`. It adds a leading decimal point on subsequent executions because I didn't do `local delim`. I've edited my answer for that issue.

Comment: I tried but can't replicate the issue anymore. it was 3 years ago anyway so maybe I just dont remember the specifics

Answer (score 15):

IP address -> Number:

```
echo 66.102.13.19 | tr . '\n' | awk '{s = s*256 + $1} END{print s}'
```

Number -> IP address:

```
(export ip=1113984275; for i in {1..4}; do s='.'$((ip%256))$s && ((ip>>=8)); done; echo ${s:1})
```

Comment: That's great, but how do we do it the other way. i.e. IP Number --> IP Address

Comment: I have update the method of how to convert IP number to IP address. :)

Comment: You can avoid the call to `tr` by specifying the record separator, ie.: `awk 'BEGIN{RS="."}...` or `awk '{s = s*256 + $1} END{print s}' RS=.`

Answer (score 4):

Binary shifting is always faster than multiplying or dividing.
Using a binary AND is faster than mod.

```
ip2dec(){ # Convert an IPv4 IP number to its decimal equivalent.
          declare -i a b c d;
          IFS=. read a b c d <<<"$*";
          echo "$(((a<<24)+(b<<16)+(c<<8)+d))";
        }
dec2ip(){ # Convert an IPv4 decimal IP value to an IPv4 IP.
          declare -i a=$((0xff)) b=$1; 
          c="$((b>>24&a)).$((b>>16&a)).$((b>>8&a)).$((b&a))";
          echo "$c";
        }

ip=66.102.13.19
a=$(ip2dec "$ip")
b=$(dec2ip "$a")
echo "$ip DecIP=$a IPv4=$b "
```

Note: This system will fail with values like `0008`.
Bash thinks it is an octal number.

To solve that, each value will have to be cleaned with something like:

```
IsDecInt()(     # Is the value given on $1 a decimal integer (with sign)?
                declare n=$1; set --
                if [[ $n =~ ^([+-]?)((0)|0*([0-9]*))$ ]]; then
                    set -- "${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}"
                else
                    exit 1
                fi
                echo "$1$3$4";
          )

  a=$(IsDecInt "$a")||{ Echo "Value $a is not an integer" >&2; exit 1; }
```

For (very) old shells: bash since 2.04, or dash or any (reasonable) shell:

```
ip2dec(){ # Convert an IPv4 IP number to its decimal equivalent.
          local a b c d;
          IFS=. read a b c d <<-_EOF_
$1
_EOF_
          echo "$(((a<<24)+(b<<16)+(c<<8)+d))";
        }

dec2ip(){   # Convert an IPv4 decimal IP value to an IPv4 IP.
            local a=$((~(-1<<8))) b=$1; 
            c="$((b>>24&a)).$((b>>16&a)).$((b>>8&a)).$((b&a))";
            echo "$c";
        }

ip=$1
a=$(ip2dec "$ip")
b=$(dec2ip "$a")
echo "$ip DecIP=$a IPv4=$b "
```

Comment: To cleanup variables `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` from leading `0` and prevent octal interpretation, you can do:
`((a=10#$a,b=10#$b,c=10#$c,d=10#$d))`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123717/removing-leading-zeros-before-passing-a-shell-variable-to-another-command#answer-11130324 Or alternatively do not `declare -i` but `echo "$(((10#$a<<24)+(10#$b<<16)+(10#$c<<8)+10#$d))";`

Answer (score 3):

my version for int to ip conversion:

`echo 3232235521| awk {'print rshift(and($1, 0xFF000000), 24) "." rshift(and($1, 0x00FF0000), 16) "." rshift(and($1, 0x0000FF00), 8) "." and($1, 0x000000FF) '}`

Answer (score 3):

Here's my take:

```
$ host google.com
google.com has address 216.58.216.142
$ ./ip2d.sh 216.58.216.142
3627735182
$ ./d2ip.sh 3627735182
216.58.216.142
```

ip2d.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=.
set -- $*
echo $(( ($1*256**3) + ($2*256**2) + ($3*256) + ($4) ))
```

d2ip.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=" " read -r a b c d  <<< $(echo  "obase=256 ; $1" |bc)
echo ${a#0}.${b#0}.${c#0}.${d#0}
```

Comment: Love it. ip2d could be a (bash) function as `ip2d() { IFS=. eval 'set -- $1'; echo ...` and d2ip could also be written `IFS=\  read -r a b c d  < <(echo "obase=256;$1" |bc)`

Comment: And shorter again: `A=($(dc -e "256o$1p"));IFS=. eval 'echo "${A[*]#0}"'` (have the same issue than the original when a quad has two leading 0).

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a simpler solution that also handles an arbitrary number of octets with no references to fixed offsets etc.

```
echo 66.102.13.19 |
    tr . '\n' |
    while read octet; do
        printf "%.08d" $(echo "obase=2;$octet" | bc)
    done |
    echo $((2#$(cat)))
```

output: 1113984275

Comment: Hello, I have a question on your answer.

Can you explain the meaning of the `$((2#$(cat)))`

Comment: @yundongxu The `cat` command reads the data piped into standard input which is a string of binary digits. The expression `$((2#...))` converts "..." from base 2 to decimal.

Answer (score 2):

Simple int to IP conversion for bash

```
dec2ip ()
{
   local v=$1
   local i1=$((v>>24&255))
   local i2=$((v>>16&255))
   local i3=$((v>>8&255))
   local i4=$((v&255))
   printf '%d.%d.%d.%d\n' $i1 $i2 $i3 $i4
}
```