# Removing leading zeros before passing a shell variable to another command

Tags: bash, strip

It turns out that iptables doesn't handle leading zeros too well. As `$machinenumber` that is used has to have a leading zero in it for other purposes, the idea is simply to create a new variable (`$nozero`) based on `$machinenumber`, where leading zeros are stripped away.

`$machinenumber` is a two-digit number between 01 and 24. Currently it's 09

`$machinetype` is 74 for now and hasn't caused any problems before.

What I have so far is:

```
nozero = (echo $machinenumber | sed 's/^0*//')
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 10.($machinetype).($nozero).0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

While I believe I'm on the right track, the code results in:

```
ERROR - Unknown string operation
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

you can also do

```
machinenumber=$(expr $machinenumber + 0)
```

Comment: This turned out to be the simplest, working approach: `iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 10.($machinetype).($machinenumber + 0).0/24 -j MASQUERADE`

Answer (score 93):

You don't need to use `sed` or another external utility. Here are a couple of ways Bash can strip the leading zeros for you.

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s "10.$machinetype.$((10#$machinenumber)).0/24" -j MASQUERADE
```

The `$(())` sets up an arithmetic context and the `10#` converts the number from base 10 to base 10 causing any leading zeros to be dropped.

```
shopt -s extglob
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s "10.$machinetype.${machinenumber##+(0)}.0/24" -j MASQUERADE
```

When `extglob` is turned on, the parameter expansion shown removes all leading zeros. Unfortunately, if the original value is 0, the result is a null string.

Comment: The `10#` is the simplest and most elegant solution I've found so far. Thank you!

Comment: `echo $((10#${machinenumber}))` works in kornshell too! I was looking for a non-bashism and this should work fine. ksh M-11/16/88f

Comment: The accepted answer is wrong.  This should be the accepted answer.  `$((10#$var))` is a new discovery for me.  I am surprised that `$((10#var))` doesn't work - I thought `$` was optional inside `((...))` for variable expansion.

Answer (score 27):

No, you make all (alomost all) correct.
You just must:

- remove spaces around `=`
- use `$()` or backticks instead of `()`

That would be correct:

```
 nozero=$(echo $machinenumber | sed 's/^0*//')
```

Also you must use variables without `()` around them. You can add `""` if you want:

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s "10.$machinetype.$nozero.0/24" -j MASQUERADE
```

And of course variables here are not necessary. You can say simply:

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s "10.$(echo $machinenumber | sed 's/^0*//').$nozero.0/24" -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: It works, cheers. What if i wanted to bake it into the iptables command, tho? I prefer not to declare any new variables.

Comment: Could you provide me with the correct syntax? My bash scripting is dodgy at best.

Answer (score 10):

I can't comment as I don't have sufficient reputation, but I would suggest you accept [Dennis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11130324/1014396) (which is really quite neat)

Firstly, I don't think that your answer is valid bash.
In my install I get:

```
> machinetype=74
> machinenumber=05
> iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 10.($machinetype).($machinenumber + 0).0/24 -j MASQUERADE
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
> echo 10.($machinetype).($machinenumber + 0).0/24
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

If I quote it I get:

```
> echo "($machinetype).($machinenumber + 0)"
(74).(05 + 0)
```

I'm assuming you mean:

```
> echo 10.$(($machinetype)).$(($machinenumber + 0)).0/24
10.74.5.0/24
```

But, of course it's still a bad solution because of octal:

```
> machinenumber=09
> echo 10.$(($machinetype)).$(($machinenumber + 0)).0/24
-bash: 09: value too great for base (error token is "09")
```

I assume that your numbers aren't 08 or 09 at the moment.

Here's Dennis's:

```
> echo $((10#09))
9
> echo $((10#00))
0
> echo $((10#00005))
5
> echo $((10#))
0
```

Admittedly, that last one might be an input validation problem for someone.

The sed solution has the problem of:

```
> echo "0" | sed 's/^0*//'

>
```

Answer (score 8):

```
nozero=$(echo $machinenumber | sed 's/^0*//')
```

Try without the spaces around `=` and with an additional `$` sign.

Answer (score 6):

A pure bash solution:

```
> N=0001023450 
> [[ $N =~ "0*(.*)" ]] && N=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
> echo $N 
1023450
```

Comment: It would be `[[ "$N" =~ ^0*(.+)$ ]] && N="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"` - that also works for N="000" and N="0". Consider also `[[ "$N" =~ ^0*([0-9]+)$ ]]`

Comment: This works even if one needs to strip leading zero from something like a date: 03.20. (mm.yy.) is converted to 3.20.

Answer (score 6):

Add the number with 0, it will remove leading zeroes

```
eg: expr 00010 + 0 #becomes 10
```

OR

```
num=00076
num=${num##+(0)}
echo $num
```

Comment: The second will work if extended globs are enabled.

Answer (score 5):

Using sed:

```
echo 000498 | sed "s/^0*\([1-9]\)/\1/;s/^0*$/0/"
498
echo 000 | sed "s/^0*\([1-9]\)/\1/;s/^0*$/0/"
0
```

Answer (score 4):

I do it by using

```
awk '{print $1 + 0}'
```

I like this better than the sed approach as it still works with numbers like 0, 000, and 001.

So in your example I would replace

```
nozero=$(echo $machinenumber | sed 's/^0*//')
```

with

```
nozero=$(echo $machinenumber | awk '{print $1 + 0}' )
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using bash, this looks like the simplest:

```
nozero=$(bc<<<$machinenumber)
```

Comment: tested as the only working version on my Mac bash-3.2

Comment: simple and works good

Answer (score 2):

I also can't comment or vote up yet, but the Duncan Irvine answer is the best.

I'd like to add a note about portability. The `$((10#0009))` syntax is not portable. It works in bash and ksh, but not in dash:

```
$ echo $((10#09))
dash: 1: arithmetic expression: expecting EOF: "10#09"

$ dpkg -s dash | grep -i version
Version: 0.5.7-2ubuntu2
```

If portability is important to you, use the sed answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you are very close.  I do not see a requirement stated for bash, but your nonzero logic is flawed.

```
nonzero=`echo $machinenumber + 0 | bc`
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 10.$machinetype.$nozero.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

Adding 0 is a common method for changing a string number into a non-padded integer.  bc is a basic calculator.  I use this method for removing space and zero padding from numbers all the time.

While I am not expert in iptables syntax, I am pretty sure the parenthesis are not necessary.  Since I already have non-word characters bordering both variables, I do not need special enclosures around them.  Word characters are;

```
[a-zA-z0-9_]
```

Using this solution, you do not lose zero as a potential value, and should be portable across all shells.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the reputation to respond, but @cullen-fluffy-jennings's response (| awk '{print $1 + 0}') is the best.

Any proper response should be:

- Short
- Standard cross-platform
- Easy to remember
- Work with 001, 000,and -001 without mistaking them for octal, blank, or throwing an error
- Work through a pipe, so it can be tacked onto other conversions without extra steps, while still being able to be used inline on preexisting variables via "echo | ".

awk '{print $1 + 0}' meets all of these goals.  Others do not.  sed messes up  on "000". $((xx + 0)) requires predefining x, and fails on values over 8. $((10#$x)) requires predefining x and fails on negative numbers. Extglob fails on zero and requires predefinition.  Etc.

Everyone has awk. It's short. It's memorable. It works in all conditions. It works inline.

It's the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just using parameter expansion operators, in a bash script, this will remove the leading zeros from the variable `a`:

```
a=003750
echo "${a#"${a%%[!0]*}"}"
```

Going from the outside in:

- `"${a#"${a%%[!0]*}"}"` removes the match to the pattern `"${a%%[!0]*}"` from the beginning of the value of `a` (yes, patterns can be expansions).
- `"${a%%[!0]*}"` removes the match to the pattern `[!0]*` from the end of the value of `a`. Because the operator `%` appears twice, it'll be greedy and so it'll remove the largest match to that pattern.
- `[!0]*` will match the pattern `[!0]` followed by anything.
- `[!0]` matches the characters indicated by `!0`
- `!0` this is *not zero*. So `"${a%%[!0]*}"` expands to the leading zeros of the value of `a`.

This will not work on a CLI interactive session. If you want to use it like that, escape the `!`:

```
a=003750
echo "${a#"${a%%[\\!0]*}"}"
```

If the parameter is `0` itself, the resulting expansion will be the null string.

Answer (score 0):

I had to revisit this code the other day due to some unrelated stuff, and due to compatibility with some other software that reads the same script, i found it a lot easiest to rewrite it into this, which should still be valid bash:

`iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 10.($machinetype).($machinenumber + 0).0/24 -j MASQUERADE`

Basically, adding 0 forces it to be interpreted as an integer, hence automatically stripping the leading zeros

Comment: Huh? `($machinenumber + 0)` isn't math syntax in bash.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have sed or awk or perl then you could use **cut** and **grep**

```
mn="$machinenumber"
while echo "$mn"|grep -q '^0';do mn=$(echo "$mn"|cut -c2-);done
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 10.($machinetype).($mn).0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

Works with both bash and dash shells.