# How to suppress leading zero in date output?

Tags: bash, date, printf, pad

I have this code:

```
printf -v s '%(%S)T' -1 # grab the current second
if ((s == 0)); then
  # at the top of the minute, run some code
fi
```

This code throws an error on the eighth and ninth second of every minute:

```
bash: ((: 08: value too great for base (error token is "08")
bash: ((: 09: value too great for base (error token is "09")
```

How can I rectify this? Basically, we need to suppress the leading zero in the date output generated by `printf`.

Comment: `s=${s##*0}` is a simply parameter expansion to remove all leading zeros.

Comment: @DavidC.RankinDav what about `s=10`? That would remove everything.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin this may be better: `shopt -s extglob; s=${s##+(0)}`.

Comment: Agreed. `extglob` provides a better way to protect non-leading zeros. Another is substring replacement, e.g. `${a//^0*/}`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The anchor should be actually `#`. However, using `${a//#0*/}` won't help (`#` is not considered an anchor here because of the extra `/`), neither will `${a/#0*/}` (`#` is considered an anchor here but it will discard everything if the number starts with at least one `0` -- because of the `*`). I see only one possible option, using extglob again: `${a/#+(0)/}` or `${a/#*(0)/}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `-` prefix in the format string, thus:

```
printf -v s '%(%-S)T' -1
```

This suppresses the leading zero.

A more generic [way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11130324/6862601) of solving this is to specify the base in Bash arithmetic this way, while keeping the `printf` command unchanged:

```
if ((10#$s == 0)); then
```

---

Related post on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange:

- [Removing leading zeros from date](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79371/removing-leading-zeros-from-date)