# How is rosparam calculating the of leading-zero integers?

Tags: python, ros, rospy

Could someone explain how ROS's rosparam command converts input and output values?
Specifically, I am surprised by the following set of commands caused by leading zeros:

```
$ rosparam set mytest 00111
$ rosparam get mytest
73
```

This isn't the conversion from binary, so what is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a bash feature, which ROS inherits when using the command-line interface. From the [arithmetic evaluation section of the bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-arithmetic-evaluation):

> Constants with a leading 0 are interpreted as octal numbers.

You could reproduce this behavior without involving ROS at all:

```
$ echo $((00111))
73 #  73 = 64 + 8 + 1
```

If you want to convert your number to decimal instead of octal, strip the leading zeroes before converting your value to an integer (see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123717/removing-leading-zeros-before-passing-a-shell-variable-to-another-command)
)

```
$ echo $((10#00111))
111
```